# Which is faster? (foreach loops and updates in Unity)

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine

I have 24 methods that need to run in an update process at all times as they calculate necessary math and it's impossible to not have it this way.

However, it's one class attached to 24 different objects all with different values assigned to the variables.

I was curious if it is faster to use a foreach loop to iterate through each object and run their method in a 50 frames per second update, or have all 24 objects running in their own 30 frames per second update?

I was trying to benchmark it on my own to see if I could find one faster than the other. Logic dictates that the loop would be faster but I just don't know.

Comment: Why did not your logging work? If you know when it is initiated resp. done use nano time and test the two cases?

Comment: What do you mean by "faster"? why does the frequency affect it? Could you clarify what you are trying to determine?

Comment: I'm trying to determine which uses less processing power.

Comment: Benchmark it! Also premature optimization is evil.

Comment: Well the game I made is already done and out on the market. I'm just doing this optimization for my own research. I've only been programming since July and this is the second game I've solo programmed and it has about 25,000 plays per day. I'm just trying to see how fast I can make my game run at this point and player feedback is helpful. Seems to run fast right now though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Update method within a monobehaviour is not actually threaded per object. The process is serial; something like this:

```
foreach GameObject >
    Awake
foreach GameObject >
    Start
main game loop >
  foreach GameObject >
    Update

blah blah blah
```

The time to do your own for each rather than relying on Update would be insignificant.

Comment: So basically it doesn't matter which way I choose. Well the foreach loop is a little cleaner IMO so I can do that way then. Thank you!